# Как сократить функции?

Tags: javascript

Привет всем! Как можно сократить вот эти функции?Переменные slider1,slider2,slider3,slider4,work_numb,work_numb2,relax_numb,relax_numb2 повторяются.

```
 $('#slider1').slider({
    value:30,
    min:0,
    max:60,
    step:1,
    create: function(event,ui){
      var val = $("#slider").slider("value");
      $("#work_numb").html(val);
    },
    slide: function(event,ui){
      $("#work_numb").html(ui.value);
    }
  });

  $('#slider2').slider({
    value:30,
    min:0,
    max:60,
    step:1,
    create: function(event,ui){
      var val = $("#slider").slider("value");
      $("#work_numb2").html(val);
    },
    slide: function(event,ui){
      $("#work_numb2").html(ui.value);
    }
  });

  $('#slider3').slider({
    value:30,
    min:0,
    max:60,
    step:1,
    create: function(event,ui){
      var val = $("#slider").slider("value");
      $("#relax_numb").html(val);
    },
    slide: function(event,ui){
      $("#relax_numb").html(ui.value);
    }
  });

  $('#slider4').slider({
    value:30,
    min:0,
    max:60,
    step:1,
    create: function(event,ui){
      var val = $("#slider").slider("value");
      $("#relax_numb2").html(val);
    },
    slide: function(event,ui){
      $("#relax_numb2").html(ui.value);
    }
  });
```

Comment: А какой-то один класс у слайдера есть?

Comment: Это не JS, это iQuery. Позиционируйте вопрос правильно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно общий код вынести в свой плагин:

```
$.fn.mySlider = function(selector) {
  $(this).slider({
    value:30,
    min:0,
    max:60,
    step:1,
    create: function(event,ui){
      var val = $("#slider").slider("value");
      $(selector).html(val);
    },
    slide: function(event,ui){
      $(selector).html(ui.value);
    }
  });
}

$('#slider1').mySlider('#work_numb');
$('#slider2').mySlider('#work_numb2');
$('#slider3').mySlider('#relax_numb');
$('#slider4').mySlider('#relax_numb2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете прописать общую функцию инициализации данного слайдера, и каждый раз вызывая передавать разные значения

> Вызов функции

```
getSlider('slider1','work_numb');
```

> Сама функция

```
function getSlider(main_selector,html_selector){

    $('#'+main_selector).slider({
    value:30,
    min:0,
    max:60,
    step:1,
    create: function(event,ui){
      var val = $("#slider").slider("value");
      $("#"+html_selector).html(val);
    },
    slide: function(event,ui){
      $("#"+html_selector).html(ui.value);
    }
  });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

```
 var dataSelectors = {
    '#slider1':'#work_numb',
    '#slider2':'#work_numb2',
    '#slider3':'#relax_numb',
    '#slider4':'#relax_numb2',
 }

 $.each(dataSelectors , function(k,v){
     $(k).slider({
        value:30,
        min:0,
        max:60,
        step:1,
        create: function(event,ui){
          var val = $("#slider").slider("value");
          $(v).html(val);
        },
        slide: function(event,ui){
          $(v).html(ui.value);
        }
    });
 })
```